# Why can't I block an ip address with iptables on debian 6?

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

I believe that I have setup the firewall correctly like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

IPT="/sbin/iptables"

# Flush old rules, old custom tables
$IPT --flush
$IPT --delete-chain

# Set default policies for all three default chains
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Enable free use of loopback interfaces
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# All TCP sessions should begin with SYN
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP

# Accept inbound TCP packets
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 81 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8181 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

# Accept outbound packets
$IPT -I OUTPUT 1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

But when I try to block an ip address from accessing my webserver, it doesn't work and the user is still able to access the server.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Appending your filtering rule at the end of all INPUT rules has no effect since all http traffic on port  80 will be accepted before.

first packet will be accepted by this rule : 
`INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT`
and all subsequent packet by this one: 
`INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

To be sure to filter all packets from xx.xx.xx.xx you should put your rule at the first position in INPUT chain.

To do that, so you put `iptables -A INPUT -s xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP` before others, either you may use this command :  `iptables -I INPUT 1 -s xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP`, to insert a the first position.

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming, your question seems to be about server configuration... so it should be posted on serverFault to reach more people.

Comment: `iptables -I INPUT -s xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP` did the trick, thanks!